# UITableViewCell + AutoLayout Content Size is not updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am creating a table view using `AutoLayout` for iOS 7 - iOS 9.

I have created a single cell prototype with *.xib* interface builder.

[image]

Inside the cell implementation I have no implementation yet.

Despite the fact, that `AutoLayout` constraints seems to be provided correctly, I am obtaining errors like this:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5a80c3b0 UILabel:0x7fad585a6c60.width == UILabel:0x7fad5ad9f2b0.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5a84c0a0 UILabel:0x7fad5ad9f2b0.leading == UILabel:0x7fad585a6c60.trailing + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5862a140 UILabel:0x7fad585a6c60.leading == MyCustomTableViewCell:0x7fad5ad88560.leading + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad58621c30 MyCustomTableViewCell:0x7fad5ad88560.trailing == UILabel:0x7fad5ad9f2b0.trailing + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5ae218c0 MyCustomTableViewCell:0x7fad5ad88560.width == 1>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad5a84c0a0 UILabel:0x7fad5ad9f2b0.leading == UILabel:0x7fad585a6c60.trailing + 10>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

When the breakpoint is reached, line `[[[0x7fad5ad9f2b0 superview] superview] recursiveDescription]` displays:

```
<VideoAnalysisVideoInformationTableViewCell: 0x7fad5ad88560; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 301; 1 35); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fad585445a0>>
   | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7fad585d9d60; frame = (0 0; 1 35); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fad585a2d30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fad585e9b40>>
   |    | <UILabel: 0x7fad585a6c60; frame = (10 5; 145 25); text = 'Score'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer =     <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fad5850b030>>
   |    | <UILabel: 0x7fad5ad9f2b0; frame = (165 5; 145 25); text = '33'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fad5ad98210>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7fad5a8cf620; frame = (15 34; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fad5a9121d0>>
```

It seems, that the content view size is incorrect. How that could happen? How could I fix this?

Comment: Don't set the frame size when using AutoLayout. You should be setting the cell size in your view controller heightForCellAtIndexPath method.

Comment: That was my first thought also. Inside the method `heightForCellAtIndexPath` cell's frame is correct. On the `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` breakpoint - not.

Answer (score 0):

You have set wrong constraints.

Give constraints like this,

Title label - leading and top

Info label - trailing and top

and select both label and give equal width. hope this will help :)

Update :

give top,leading,trailing and fix height to both label. 
and give equal width

Comment: This won't work because of vertical hugging. Also the horizontal spacing should't affect anything. Have you any idea why cell & content view width is only 1 px?

Comment: No there shouldn't be 1 px by default...!

Comment: I have added a symbolic breakpoint `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` to debug `AutoLayout` constraints and logged structure (read the question above). It shows width - 1px.

Comment: And what are you trying to imply? That the horizontal spacing messes the things?

Comment: And also your updated code generates warnings about the width (and this makes sense).

Comment: Yes I did clean previous constraints.

Comment: I have taken one view and put two labels in it and this constraints works fine.